# printing output after every input in for loop python

Tags: python

each time I type a number in the console, "-" or "*" is printed immediately. How can I avoid that, that is, the characters to be printed at the end. Look at pics [image][image]

```
n = int(input("Enter positive integer"))
if n < 1:
    print("That ain't positive integer")
else:
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        num = int(input(f"Enter {i} number "))
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(num * "*")
        else:
            print(num * "-")
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: u have picture, it should output "-" and "*" at the end not after every input of a number

Answer (score 0):

This will work out using `append`

```
n = int(input("Enter positive integer"))
a = []
if n < 1:
    print("That ain't positive integer")
else:
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        num = int(input(f"Enter {i} number "))
        if i % 2 == 0:
            a.append(num * "*")
        else:
            a.append(num * "-")
demo = [print(data) for data in a]
```

Comment: is it possible without lists ?

Comment: may be not possible ..